# writing django signal hook to check whether user already exists

Tags: django, django-signals, django-users

We recently switched from one LDAP system to another. Unfortunately, not only the LDAP server changed but all usernames did too.

I managed to configure `django_auth_ldap` to deal with two LDAP servers, however I can not prevent the creation of new users in my database.

I tried to hook up a listener to `django_auth_ldap.backend.populate_user.connect` but that signal gets evaluated `after` a user had been created.

So what's the best approach to do:

- authenticate user
- check if username in database
- check for alternative username in database
- update username if necessary (old & new user mapping found)
- create new user if not found anywhere

**EDIT** I'm aware of signal handlers, but I don't know how (and where in the code) to solve the task of preventing duplicate user creation. Where should I hook my code up that checks for old vs new usernames?

**EDIT2:**

I've tried to following, but still a `new_name` user is being created.

```
# touple of old user and new user names
username_list = [('old_name', 'new_name') ]

@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def check_if_user_exists(sender, **kwargs):
    try:
        print "check_if_user_exists:"
        user_instance = kwargs['instance']
        print user_instance
        if any([x[1] == user_instance.username for x in username_list]):
            print "new user name found!"
            # get old username
            user = User.objects.get(username = x[0])
            user.username = user_instance.username
            return user
        else:
            print "user not found :("
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print ('user not found')
        pass
```

Comment: Would this link help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save ?

Comment: @limelights sure, but it doesn't help me, since it's just a link to signal docs. I need to some input regarding the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you implement a `signal_handler` on a `pre_save`. These should live in your `models.py`.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def check_if_user_exists_based_on_whatever(sender, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = MyModel.objects.get(kwargs['instance'].<field_to_get_on_model>)
        user.username = "new_username"
        user.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        user = MyModel.create(name="mymyself", lastname="andI")
```

This is just a basic example, I don't really know all of your validation logic. ^_^

Comment: This doesn't fuse with a LDAP binding but I guess you could surpass that hurdle.

Comment: so instead of `MyModel` I can also use `django.contrib.auth.models.User`?  do I have to return `user`?

Comment: Yep and Nope. You don't have to return anything.

Comment: Edited code, i had 'user_id' as key in `kwargs` this was wrong, it should be `instance`. Sorry. See here what's availiable to you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save

Comment: I tried your code (see my EDIT #2) but I still end up with new users.

Comment: You are calling user.save() somewhere, thats why you get new ones. You have to raise an exception when/if you find a user in your signal.

Comment: some library might be calling user.save() somewhere. but I can't control that. So how should I modify above code to detect existing users and simply change the username?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28264/discussion-between-limelights-and-memyself)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own authentication backend, overwriting `get_or_create_user`.